# Serializer - What does the serializer object needs of normalizers to deserialize json into object

Tags: symfony, json-deserialization

I want to convert this json

```
[
    {
        "name": "1",
        "created": "2019-12-08T15:43:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "2",
        "created": "2019-12-08T15:43:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

into a single object.

```php
class Persons
{
    /**
     * @var array<Person>
     */
    public array $persons = [];
}

class Person
{
    public string $name = '';
    public DateTimeInterface $created;
}
```

And im using this as my serializer

```php
$encoder = [
    new JsonEncoder(),
];

$normalizer = [
    new DateTimeNormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(),
];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);
```

When running this

```php
$persons = $serializer->deserialize($json, Persons::class, 'json');
var_dump($persons);
```

`$persons` is a empty array

So which normalizers do I need for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json doesn't represent a Persons object, it is an array of Persons. according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays
you can append `[]` to your class name to deserialize an array of objects:

```
$persons = $serializer->deserialize($json, Person::class.'[]', 'json');
```

Then, `$persons` should be an array of Person objects. Please note the Person::class being the singular, not the plural.

To deserialize into Persons::class - if you insist for whatever reason - your json would either have to be embedded into the following json

```
{"persons": <here your json>}
```

or you need to implement your own serializer (to be more specific, your own denormalizer), and hop through some hoops to use it. (I'm not quite certain, but I believe the expected doc notation for arrays of objects in php is `@var []Person`)

Comment: I updated my code to return array of Person[] - and it works now. Now after adding DateTimeNormalizer - I get - Person::$created must be an instance of DateTimeInterface, string used

Comment: @Martin You should probably create a proper second question, with code and all. I don't want to imagine what your code looks like. No offense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because you need to match the operation with encoder/decoder - `JsonEncoder` for `serialize` and `JsonDecoder` for `deserialize` calls :)

After adding `JsonDecoder`, I believe it should work...